# Do I need more sources or need Load Balancer?

Tags: load-balancing, fedora

I am not a Pro but I did a fully working Fedora server and hosted my website on it, I did a small traffic test, @ 100 visitors both RAM and CPU were full, do I need load balancer or I need more RAM and CPU?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loadbalancer is used in a clustered environment in order to achieve high availability. You will eventually consider having high avail. by the time your traffic goes higher and if your website's avail. is important enough. However the current situation seems like you need more resources if you are sure that your webserver and applications are working at optimum resource utilization.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood when I will need the Load Balancer.